# How to request offline_access from Google using .AddOpenIdConnect() in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, openid-connect, google-openid

I know Microsoft provides a Google-specific OIDC package (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google`) which takes an option in `.AddGoogle()` to specify `AccessType` that can be set to `offline`.

But can this be done using the standard ASP.NET Core OIDC package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` and `.AddOpenIdConnect()`?

With Microsoft account we can simply request the `offline_access` scope and it works perfectly. But it does not work with Google and results in an `invalid_scope` error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured this out. Google uses the `access_type` parameter for offline access request instead of scope. So we can handle the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event in `OpenIdConnectOptions` to add this parameter:

```
 options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
 {
   context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("access_type", "offline");
   return Task.CompletedTask;
 };
```

Comment: This is such an obscure way to do it, this answer needs to have a few more 1000's upvotes.